# itemtest is behaving strangely

Tags: team-fortress-2

I wanted to mess around with some weapons in TF2, so I went to the map "itemtest". I know that the weapons have to be mechanic-changing in order to work differently, but some strange things happened while I was doing this:

- The Atomizer, Winger, Machina, Disguise Kit, and Invis-Watches were nowhere on the list
- The Rescue Ranger shot Huntsman arrows
- Crit-a-Cola worked like the Bonk! Atomic Punch
- The Sandman/Wrap Assasin wouldn't let me fire the projectile
- The Vaccinator didn't have the resistances
- I can't be hurt in any way

as well as some other things. Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if it's just how itemtest works?

Comment: Have you edited your game files in any way?

Comment: @EatMyTacoCrumbs No, I haven't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just how the [itemtest](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Itemtest) system works. Designed for model creators to ensure that their stuff is working properly, it makes no effort to actually implement whatever mechanics are involved on any existing items you try to equip. It's not a potential way to mess around with items you don't have.

Comment: I understand why the mechanics don't work properly, but why are some of the weapons missing? Is it just a bug?

Comment: Probably just yet another TF2 bug that makes no sense whatsoever. Could be as simple as Valve forgetting to put them on the list, could be something of insane complexity that no one has ever imagined.